# Memory usage in php script and bandwidth relation

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel

Is there any relation between php script execution memory usage and bandwidth??
I used laravel and codeigniter

> laravel

[image]

> codeigniter

[image]

I want to know impact on bandwidth.

Comment: memory usage only applies to the server environment. there is no corellation.

Comment: Is there any article or source for learn more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no connection of memory usage with bandwidth. Memory is just like the ram of our desktop pc. As your data sending over internet is not related to how much of your ram is being used so the case with this situation.

Comment: When more than one user accessing site than how much will be memory_usage?

Comment: Yes it increases memory usage, And i think there is no particular answer for how much.